# Get internal hourly rate via the ActiveCollab API

Tags: activecollab

I configured a cost for each user of the platform according to the following [tutorial](https://activecollab.com/help/books/budgeting/profitability) (People > Show internal rates > click in not set > set internal hourly rate > save). But now I need to query this data via API in my own application.

I checked all the routes listed in the [documentation](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/index.html) and I didn't find anywhere how to return this data.

I can only return the default hourly rate of the job type or the value configured for the project. How do I get the internal hourly rate for each user or cost and profitability of each member?

I tried to retrieve this data through requests like:

```
/users
/users/{userId}
/projects/{projectId}/budget
/projects
/projects/{projectId}
/projects/{projectId}/time-records
/projects/{projectId}/time-records/{timeRecordId}
/tasks
/tasks/{taskId}
```

but no request returns the internal hourly rate, only the hourly rate of the job type or project

Answer (score 0):

User's current internal rate can be retrieved by sending a GET request to `api/v1/users/:user_id/internal-rate`.

To get all of user's internal rates, both historical and future (if present), send a GET request to `api/v1/users/:user_id/internal-rates`.

To get rates of active users, send a GET request to `api/v1/users/internal-rates`. Only users which have a set rate will be returned.

Prefix all API calls with your account URL (https://app.activecollab.com/:account_id/).

Comment: If I need the internal rate of all users, is there a route for this or do I need to make a request for each user?

Comment: @Herbert I updated the answer and added that API end-point that returns rates for active users (who have it set).